# extract a specific word in bash

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk, cut

I have some lines in below forms:

```
-rw-r--r-- sten/sefan anonymous 8593 2011-12-05 18:28 8M
-rw-r--r-- sten/sefan 8593 2011-12-05 18:28 8M
```

How can I get the `8593` one-liner?

The lines are retrieved by performing some `dry-run` of archives, e.g.:

```
$ tar jtvf zip64support.tar.bz2 
-rw-r--r-- stefan.bodewig/Domain Users 16195018 2011-10-14 21:05 100k_Files.zip
-rw-r--r-- stefan.bodewig/Domain Users 14417258 2011-10-14 21:05 100k_Files_7ZIP.zip
```

or:

```
$ tar jtvf bla.tar.bz2 
-rw-r--r-- tcurdt/tcurdt   610 2007-11-14 18:19 test1.xml
-rw-r--r-- tcurdt/tcurdt    82 2007-11-14 18:19 test2.xml
```

Specifically to get the number in a line with `YYYY-mm-dd` after it.

Comment: If that is something like `ls` output, then you shouldn't parse it. Where is the data coming from and what's the meaning of the number you extract?

Comment: e.g.:$ tar jtvf bla.tar.bz2 
-rw-r--r-- tcurdt/tcurdt   610 2007-11-14 18:19 test1.xml
-rw-r--r-- tcurdt/tcurdt    82 2007-11-14 18:19 test2.xml

Comment: @yuwang I suggest you add the tar part in your question. because your example lets one think that it is from ls command.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The command you are after to get the filesizes in the current directory is

```
$ stat -c %s *
```

You do **not** want to use `bash`,`awk` or `cut` to do this and your question is a great reason why as in the first line it would be the fourth column and in the second it's the third. Parsing the output of `ls` [**is not recommended!**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

---

**Edit:**

Since the column is number is gaurenteed I would use `grep` with [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
$ tar jtvf zip64support.tar.bz2|grep -Po '[0-9]+(?= [0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})' 
16195018
14417258
```

Comment: Also take a look at the [stat manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/stat) for more format options. Use double quotes for the format eg: `stat -c "%s %z" <file>`.

Comment: `stat` works for files under file system, I'm using `-t` since I don't want to **extract** the files inside the archive.

Comment: Correct, you should have including this information from the start. I have added a solution using `grep`.

Answer (score 2):

give this a try:

```
tar jtvf bla.tar.bz2|awk '$0=$3'
```

in your question you mentioned

> get the number in a line with YYYY-mm-dd after it.

if you really want to do with grep:

```
tar ... |grep -oP '\d+(?= \d{4}-)'
```